# Software for cutting and joining videos of any format

Tags: windows-7, video, software-rec

I need a software that should be able to cut and join any video format.

I'm using Windows 7, and one software I got was not working with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Freemake Video Converter](http://www.freemake.com/free_video_converter/) seems to do what you want plus a lot more. A software that supports "any video format" may be hard to come by but this supports quite a few.

Comment: +1 for this cool stuff. Great tool to split the video and the conversion formats are great. I liked it because you can choose your track in a dual audio movie.

Comment: Great after using I found no need of joiner just split the part by selecting. But there is no option to save the video exact much time consumed but all the ways pretty good it is.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something to join files, check out [**SUPER**](http://www.erightsoft.com/S6Kg1.html) (download link at the bottom where it says "Download SUPER setup file").

Don't be scared by the interface, it's a really good piece of software. One advertised feature is joining of format-identical files. As it's based on ffmpeg, it'll read and write almost every possible format.

You can't use it to cut files though, as it's not a real video *editing* software.

Comment: +1 "as it's not a real video editing software."